# Separate set of administrators for a subdomain in G Suite

Tags: google-workspace

I work for a small non-profit and we were approached by a sister organization about having a subdomain under our G suite account. So we are company.org and this other group might be sister-org.company.org. My question is about administrators. I don't want their folks monkeying with any of our users/data. Is there a way to create a subdomain in G suite and allow their folks manage the users without having access to our users?

Comment: You can't set different policies or configuration settings for different domains directly. However, you can put all users from one domain into an organizational unit and all users from another domain into a different unit, and then apply different policies to each organizational unit.I think this will help you https://support.google.com/a/answer/182081

Answer (score 0):

Great answer Scaff in addition to the link you posted https://support.google.com/a/answer/6129577?hl=en is also helpful.